# Google Compute Engine, options for data restore after rm w/o snapshot

Tags: google-compute-engine

I just rm'ed what shouldnt have.
I shut the VM down with "Stop" from the Console.
I do not have recent snapshots.
I am now creating an image, download it and try to restore the files from the file system.

Is there any other way beside snapshots to get my data back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly there is no option other that snapshots...I got my stuff back. What I did:

- Made another VM Instance with one of googles standard image
- In the settings of the affected VM, set that the disks are not deleted when the VM is deleted
- delete the VM (gcloud command, you can here also specify to keep "all" disks)
- (these steps are necessary when the affected disk is a boot disk, since it can not be detached from the VM. An option might be, to add a sencond disk and make this the boot disk)
- attach the disks to the newly created vm, preferably readonly (there is a gcloud command for attaching disks)
- check /dev/disk/by-id and identify the affected disk
- once done, you can refer it with the name, eg: google-persistent-disk-2-part1 for the data recovery tools (scalpel, extundelete, foremost)

I used foremost on centos and added to the config to search for python files. And lastly find, xargs and grep to identify my files.